# Search for any of a list of strings inside another string

Tags: sql, string, hive

I need to identify records with valid addresses by comparing the address fields against a list of street-like words.

So the code would look something like:

```
set street_list = 'STREET', 'ROAD', 'AVENUE', 'DRIVE', 'WAY', 'PLACE' (etc.)
; 

create table [new table] as 
select * 
from [source table] 
where [address line 1] (contains any word from STREET_LIST) or 
      [address line 2] (contains any word from STREET_LIST) or 
      [address line 3] (contains any word from STREET_LIST)
;
```

Is this possible?

Using LostReality's regexp suggestion, I got as far as:

```
select * 
from [source table]
where upper([address line 1]) regexp '.* STREET.*|.* ST.*|.* ROAD.*|.* RD.*|.* CLOSE.*|.* LANE.*|.* LA.*|.* AVENUE.*|.* AVE.*|.* DRIVE.*|.* DR.*|.* HOUSE.*|.* WAY.*|.* PLACE.*|.* SQUARE.*|.* WALK.*|.* GROVE.*|.* GREEN.*|.* PARK.*|.* PK.*|.* CRESCENT.*|.* TERRACE.*|.* PARADE.*|.* GARDEN.*|.* GARDENS.*|.* COURT.*|.* COTTAGES.*|.* COTTAGE.*|.* MEWS.*|.* ESTATE.*|.* RISE.*|.* FARM.*' 
;
```

and it seems to work.

But I have two small problems with it:

1) how do I write the regexp on more than one line so it's easier to read?

2) is there any way of putting that regexp into a macro variable because I want to check 5 address lines and I don't want 5 copies of the same expression.

Thanks

Comment: If hiveQL doesn't support it, you could enter those values into a temporary table and use an `WHERE IN` clause

Comment: Hi dustytrash, I'm brand new to Hive so I haven't seen that one yet.  What would be the syntax?  Thanks

Comment: Hy, did you try to use RLIKE operator ? You can probably generate a regex from your list and use it as a single criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Hive. You can put regexp pattern in the variable and also you can use macro, fixed your template:

```
set hivevar:street_list ='STREET|ST|ROAD|RD|CLOSE|LANE|LA|AVENUE|AVE|DRIVE|DR|HOUSE|WAY|PLACE|SQUARE|WALK|GROVE|GREEN|PARK|PK|CRESCENT|TERRACE|PARADE|GARDEN|GARDENS|COURT|COTTAGES|COTTAGE|MEWS|ESTATE|RISE|FARM';

--boolean macro for using in the WHERE
create temporary macro contains_word(s string) (upper(s) rlike ${hivevar:street_list} ) ;

with some_table as ( --use your table instead of this synthetic example
select stack(2,'some string containing STREET and WALK',
               'some string containing something else') as str
) --use your table instead of this synthetic example

--use macro in your query
select str from some_table 
 where contains_word(str);
```

Result:

```
OK
some string containing STREET and WALK
Time taken: 0.229 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Use `OR` like in your question:

```
where contains_word(address_line_1) OR contains_word(address_line_2) ...
```

Hope you have got the idea